# How to create setup file for 32 bit outlook on 64 bit Windows OS?

Tags: c#, outlook, windows-installer, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to create an outlook Add-in for 32 bit office installed on 64 bit operating system.

The code is working fine in 64 bit office in 64 bit OS, but reinstalling package(with Office 32 bit)
is not working.

*The Add-in is not loading inside Outlook.*

Can anybody suggest me any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

See [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019).